# Fuzzy searching path in autohotkey

Tags: path, autohotkey

Since I am using jetbrains product and their update change the filepath of the installation directory, I have to keep updating the executable path. Is there a way to do a fuzzy search?

For example instead of having to change:

```
Run "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.3.2\bin\webstorm.exe"

Run 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2017.1.1\bin\webstorm.exe"
```

I want to just do:

```
Run 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm*\bin\webstorm.exe"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Executes C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm*\bin\webstorm.exe**

```
Loop C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm*, 2
  Run %A_LoopFileFullPath%\bin\webstorm.exe
```

Comment: Just remember to remove the earlier executables or the first match will run (and maybe all the others, too).

Comment: @PGilm is there anyway to always match the last one?

Comment: instead of using `run` inside the loop, use `A_LoopFileTimeModified` to find and remember the most recent executable.  after the loop completes, `run` it.